# getting all the mac address in the network android

Tags: android

Is it possible to get all the mac address connected to my network using the android application? I just want to list all the mac address of the device connected to my network.

This is my code but it is not working:

```
class loadMacClickListener implements OnClickListener
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
                 WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                 mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                 mWifiManager.startScan();
                 List<ScanResult> results = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
                 for (ScanResult result : results) 
                 {
                     listItems.add(String.valueOf(result));      
                 }
                 ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
                 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                 lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to pinpoint the actual problem, since "it's not working" is not a good description of the issue. However, based on the documentation, I can say, that you're not retrieving the results of the scan properly. `startScan()` method returns the results of the scan asynchronously, via a broadcast with `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` action. So you should register a `BroadcastReceiver` that will listen to this action and only in its `onReceive()` you can call `getScanResults()`.